# autosys - get the list of jobs that are scehduled in a particular time though unix command

Tags: autosys

I am working on an automation, where I will get the list of jobs that did not start to run even though the scheduled time has crossed. I am going to get the list based on an 2 hour time gap.

Now my question is how to get the list of jobs that are scheduled on a particular time period on that particular day.

For eg., 22-03-3018 08:00 - 10:00 am list of jobs scheduled on this period

I want to execute the command in unix.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your linux system is set up, you can look in:

```
/var/spool/cron/* (user crontabs)
/etc/crontab (system-wide crontab)
```

also, many distros have:

```
/etc/cron.d/* These configurations have the same syntax as /etc/crontab

/etc/cron.hourly, /etc/cron.daily, /etc/cron.weekly, /etc/cron.monthly
```

These are simply directories that contain executables that are executed hourly, daily, weekly or monthly, per their directory name.

On top of that, you can have at jobs (check /var/spool/at/*), anacron (/etc/anacrontab and /var/spool/anacron/*) and probably others I'm forgetting.

Answer (score 0):

In Autosys there is no easy way through using autosys native cmd's

However you can get all this information from the DB it is in the WCC DB and the table is dbo.MON_JOB query would be to get you started:

```
    SELECT [NAME]
      ,[NEXT_TIME]
  FROM [CAAutosys11_3_5_WCC_PRD].[dbo].[MON_JOB]
  WHERE [NEXT_TIME] > '1970'
  ORDER BY [NEXT_TIME] ASC
```

Let me know if you need more clarification.